# SQL query search ampersand &

Tags: sql, sql-server, special-characters

Need to write a SQL query to search special character in a column. Text needed to search is 'R&D' but issue is that SQL server 2005 is taking it as a logical operator.

Comment: Can you post the query you are using?

Comment: select Column_Name from Table_Name
where contains(Column_Name,'R&D')

Comment: Maybe edit your question title to specifically mention contains()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using parameters, correct?
Because if you do NOT use parameters, it works (see the other answers).

What doesn't work is this:

```
declare @tmp nvarchar(20)
set @tmp = 'R&D'

select * from MyTable where MyColumn = @tmp
```

The only way that I found to make it work with parameters is doing it like this:

```
declare @tmp nvarchar(20)
set @tmp = 'R&D'

select * from MyTable where MyColumn like '%' + @tmp + '%'
```

---

**EDIT:**

First of all, I need to know if you're using parameters or not.

If not, I don't understand the problem at all.
One of these will work (with or without LIKE):

```
select * from MyTable where MyColumn = 'R&D'
select * from MyTable where MyColumn like '%R&D%'
```

If you **do** work with parameters, my above solution ( ... like '%' + @tmp + '%') is the only one that I know of.

---

**EDIT 2**

Now that I know that the data type is "text":
The problem is that you can only search text with LIKE (not with '=') and you can't index a text column to increase speed.
The text data type is deprecated, so you should change it into varchar(max) anyway.
And varchar(max) doesn't have the limitations that text has: you can search it with '=' and you can index it.

So that would be the correct solution: change it from text to varchar(max) and everything will work!

Comment: Like is taking so much time. Any other option?

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * From dbo.MyTable
Where MyColumn like '%R&D%'
```

or you could use this instead of `like`:

```
Select * From dbo.MyTable
Where PatIndex('%R&D%', MyColumn) > 0
```

Comment: Like is taking so much time. Any other option?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @tbl table
(
    textcol varchar(50)
)

insert into @tbl select 'R&D'
insert into @tbl select 'What is R&D'
insert into @tbl select 'SometextR&DAndsometext'
insert into @tbl select 'This Row will not return'

select * from @tbl where textcol like '%R&D%'
```

Comment: Like is taking so much time. Any other option?

Comment: How much time? What is the data type of your column? What kind of data do you have?

Comment: Comparetively long. Right now we are looking for alternatives. If found, great, not, live with it. Datatype of column is text. Data is huge chunk of text character.

Comment: To be accurate, it is taking 1 min and 47 sec using LIKE .. :(